# Angular 7 export json data into HTML table. Element name contains dash(-)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html-table

I am grabbing some data in json format from a 3rd party api I don't have control over.  The data comes back like this.

```
        "Hotel": "SponsoredInterContinental Marine Drive",
        "Best-price": "US$\u00a0378US$\u00a0180InterContinental",
        "vendor3-price": "US$378",
        "vendor1": "Expedia.com",
        "vendor1-price": "US$181",
        "vendor2": "Booking.com",
        "vendor2-price": "US$257",
        "vendor3": "Cancelon"
```

I am able to output the data into my html table, but some of the keys have dashes(-) in the name.  This is causing issues in my typescript when I try to access the element using

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="best_price">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="table-header"> Best Price </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Best-price}} </td>
  </ng-container>
```

I get just blank data being returned for that index, but there is definitely data in the Obeservable array.  I created an observable that uses snake case key declarations, but I can't access the element.  How can I access the "Best-price" key of the array.

Observable object

```
export interface Room {
    hotel: string;
    best_price: string;
    vendor_1: string;
    vendor_2: string;
    vendor_3: string;
    vendor_1_price: string;
    vendor_2_price: string;
    vendor_3_price: string;
}
```

Component typescript

```
export class RoomsComponent implements OnInit {


  displayedColumns: string[] = ['hotel', 'best_price', 'vendor_1', 'vendor_2', 'vendor_3', 'vendor_1_price', 'vendor_2_price', 'vendor_3_price'];
  dataSource: Room[];

  constructor(private roomsService: RoomsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getRooms();
  }

  getRooms(): void {
    this.roomsService.getRooms().subscribe(
      data => { this.dataSource = data['comparison'] },
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log('done loading rooms'));

    // this.dataSource = this.roomsService.getRooms()['comparison'];
    console.log(this.dataSource);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you can use rxjs map function to map your response to remove the dashes before it get into your model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `{{element['Best-price']}}` instead of `{{element.Best-price}}`

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing using `{{element["Best-price"]}}` and see if that works. Properties can be accessed in objects using a string key.